# "If word gets out" vs "should word get out"

Tags: grammar

Why does the first sentence have a plural for the word "get" while the second sentence doesn't?

(1) "If word **gets** out"

(2) "should word **get** out"

Answer (score 2):

First: the "-s" isn't a plural; it marks the third person singular form of the verb.

The second example is presumably the start of a conditional, like: "Should word get out, it would ruin the surprise." There the "should" comes before "word" due to subject/auxiliary inversion. But the same thing occurs without the inversion in ordinary statements like "Word should get out," using "should" to express a requirement.

So let's consider that sentence:

> Word **should get** out.

Roughly following Huddleston and Pullum (2002), the main verb in that sentence is the auxiliary "should." This verb takes as its complement the bare infinitival verb phrase "get out." Since the verb "get" is thus a (bare) infinitive rather than an ordinary finite verb, it does not inflect for number or person.

Compare some similar examples:

> 1. Word **will get** out.
> 2. Word **may get** out.
> 3. Word **could get** out
> 4. Word **must get** out.